# Combining multiple nodes into one and map all the relations to that node neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a sellers node and buyers node with the same business name.

When I try to match using the code:

```
MATCH (p:Sellers)-[rel:sells]->(o:Buyers)

RETURN p, rel, o;
```

It returns the graph :
[image: 01AAAC is present twice(As a seller and a buyer) in this graph]

and the data :

```
p,rel,o

{"Seller":01AAAC}","{""invoices":5}","{"Buyer":03AAAG}

{"Seller":01AAXP}","{"invoices":8}","{"Buyer":01AAAC}

{"Seller":27AAFF}","{"invoices":2}","{"Buyer":01AAAC}
```

But I'm trying to create rather a graph like this :

[image: 01AAAC is present only once in this graph]

Can you kindly help me with an appropriate cypher query to create the above visualisation.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've given this a bit more thought and ideally, your model wouldn't differentiate between :Buyer and :Seller nodes, you'd just have one node label, say :Entity which sells to another node of the same label.

[image: Single node type Entity]

However, we live in the real world and you may need to label nodes as :Buyer and :Seller, in which case, your only option would be to add a :Seller label to any :Buyers that sell and a :Buyer label to any :Sellers that buy. This would mean you end up with some nodes having two labels, one for each status they can be in, but it would  enable you to visualise what you want to:
[image: Node with two labels]

As you can see, the highlighted node has two labels.

Unfortunately, you will not be able to generate this representation from the model you have as your :Buyer node 01AAAC is a completely different node to :Seller 01AAAC and they have no shared relationship between them.

Answer (score 0):

if you remove the label constraint from your nodes, you should get all nodes and relationships between any two nodes that are have a sells relationship

```
MATCH (a)-[:sells]-(b)
return *
```

Comment: Yes, don't worry about the nodes being 'Buyers' or ;Sellers', just let the relationship do the work. The relationship is directional and implies which end is the buyer and which end is the seller.